# Преобразовать double в RGB(Qcolor)

Tags: c++, qt

Необходимо значение double преобразовать в цвет, чтобы потом использовать в функции `SetPixel(x,y,qRGB)`. Есть такой код преобразования, но по-моему он не работает.

```
int red = Math.Min((int)(X * 256), 255);
int green = Math.Min((int)((X * 256 - red) * 256), 255);
int blue = Math.Min((int)(((X * 256 - red) * 256 - green) * 256), 255);
```

Comment: Под qt вы имели в виду qml ?

Comment: Зачем. Просто среда разработки

Comment: Пример привести можете? Значение double <-> значение RGB ?

Comment: Допустим у нас есть числа от 0 до 5, с двумя знакми после запятой(0.15 и т.п). 0 -это 0, 5 это 255

Comment: @Optimus, т.е. `double` — это просто яркость в тонах серого?

Comment: Ок, допустим вот число - 0.4 (red), 255 - это 5.0. Тогда 255*(0.4/5.0) - то что Вам нужно ? `((X-minX)/(maxX - minX)*255)`. Или у Вас в одном double есть информация и о red и о green и о blue ?

Comment: Да все в исполнении градации серого, потому что в одном double нельзя хранить сразу все 3 значения же?

Comment: Откровенно говоря, я не знаю, что это за кодирование, но упаковать цвет в RGB в один `double` без сомнения возможно. Если предположить, что каждый цвет имеет значение от 0 до 255, то упаковать можно, например, так `red + (256 * green) + (65536 * blue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Да все в исполнении градации серого
>
> ---
>
> Допустим у нас есть числа от 0 до 5, с двумя знакми после запятой(0.15 и т.п). 0 -это 0, 5 это 255

Тогда всё просто:

```
constexpr double minColorValue = 0, maxColorValue = 5.0;

double X = getMyColorValue ();
X = (X - minColorValue) / (maxColorValue - minColorValue)  // ужимаем значения в диапазон 0÷1
QColor col = QColor::fromRGBF (X,X,X);    
SetPixel(x,y,col.rgb());
```

или, что в данном случае тоже самое:

```
QColor col = QColor::fromHSVF (0,0,X);
```

или

```
QColor col = QColor::fromHSLF (0,0,X);
```

см. документацию по [`QColor`](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qcolor.html)

**Updated**

Если я правильно понял исходную задачу, то для каждого пикселя генерируемой картинки есть значение и нужно отобразить его в градиенте цветов скажем от красного (для `0.0`) и максимум (`1.0`) зелёным. Для того чтобы получить промежуточные цвета градиента применяют **цветовую интерполяцию** (**color interpolation**). В самом примитивном варианте это будет нечто следующее:

```
QColor col1 = QColor::fromRGB (255, 0, 0);
QColor col2 = QColor::fromRGB (0, 255, 0);
double fac = getMyColorValue ();
QColor target = QColor::fromRGB (
                    col1.red()  * fac + col2.red()   * (1-fac),
                    col1.green()* fac + col2.green() * (1-fac),
                    col1.blue() * fac + col2.blue()  * (1-fac)
                );
SetPixel(x,y,col.rgb());
```

В более приятных/практичных/интересных вариантах можно проводить интерполяцию в пространстве hsv/hsl, избавиться от плавающей арифметики, добавлять дополнительные цвета итд.

Comment: Спасибо. А возможно ли такое, чтобы число double[от 0 до 5] перевести в полноценный RGB?

Comment: @Optimus, что ты имеешь в виду под «полноценным RGB»?

Comment: Ну если преобразовывать в одно значение от 0 до 255 это понятно и как оказалось не сложно. А можно как то преобразовать double в RGB - все 3 значения?

Comment: @Optimus, не совсем понимаю. что ты хочешь получить от такого преобразования... просто равномерно отобразить числовой отрезок [0;5] на пространство RGB?

Comment: Да, что-то подобное. Я видел вот такие преобразование(в вопросе код).

Comment: @Optimus, эти формулы бессмысленные или неправильно записаны... самое простое, но не непрерывное можно отобразить как-то так: `uint32_t val = X/5.0*256*256; uint8_t r=val&0xFF; uint8_t g = (val&0xFF00)>>8; uint8_t b = (val&0xFF0000)>>16;` ... чтобы отображение было непрерывным и равнозначным надо будет подумать... скорей всего проще будет задавать его в HSL-пространстве, но ради равномерности нужно будет добавить какие-то нелинейные коэффициенты.... но всё это звучит как перебор... собственно, зачем это всё нужно?

Comment: ЗЫ: см [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy)

Comment: Есть картинка в градации серого, по значением пикселей по формулам вычисляются значения(плотность допустим) и потом нужно по этому значению сделать картинку цветную в формате tif

Comment: @Optimus, дополнил в ответ